# how to read binary file content as strings?

Tags: c++, filestream, binaryfiles

I need to read 16 bits from the binary file as `std::string` or `char *`. For example, a binary file contains `89 ab cd ef`, and I want to be able to extract them as `std::string`s or `char *`. I have tried the following code:

```
ifstream *p = new ifstream();
char *buffer;  
p->seekg(address, ios::beg);  
buffer = new char[16];  
memset(buffer, 0, 16);  
p->read(buffer, 16);
```

When I try to `std::cout` the buffer, nothing appeared. How can I read these characters in the binary file?

EDIT: I was looking for the buffer to be a int type such as "0x89abcdef". Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: What is the value of `address` when this code executes?

Comment: Did you open the file? Also, probably a better idea to declare `*p` on the stack: `ifstream p("somefile.txt");`

Comment: What are you hoping to get in your buffer? Do you want it to contain four bytes with values 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF respectively? Or are you trying to get some textual representation of those values (e.g., a string like `"89 ab cd ef"`)?

Comment: If you're in Linux you can use `strings bin_file_path` to get a list of all the strings from a binary file

Comment: (Note: although your question would be improved if it addressed the points in my comments above, it is extremely likely that anthony-arnold's first question points to the main cause of your troubles.)

Comment: When you attempt to read data from a file, you should always check whether the attempt succeeded. For instance, when `ifstream::read` fails to read as many bytes as you asked for it sets some flags on the stream object which you can check with `ifstream::fail` and `ifstream::eof`.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan is right. `p->good()` is probably returning false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    if (ifstream input("filename"))
    {
        std::string s(2 /*bytes*/, '\0' /*initial content - irrelevant*/);
        if (input.read(&s[0], 2 /*bytes*/))
            std::cout << "SUCCESS: [0] " << std::hex << (int)s[0] << " [1] " << (int)s[1] << '\n';
        else
            std::cerr << "Couldn't read from file\n";
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open file\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a binary stream as though it were text.

You *can*, of course, read as binary (by using "file.read()" and "file.write()" methods on your stream object).  Just like what you're doing now :)

You can also convert binary to text: "convert to hex text string" and "uuencode base 64" are two common ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read the bytes as numbers (of type long long probably).
Then you can print those using formatting specifiers [like this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/51591/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int x =   2;
    int y = 255;

    cout << showbase // show the 0x prefix
         << internal // fill between the prefix and the number
         << setfill('0'); // fill with 0s

    cout << hex << setw(4) << x << dec << " = " << setw(3) << x << endl;
    cout << hex << setw(4) << y << dec << " = " << setw(3) << y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```